# City maps portal

Tags: html, css, reactjs, openlayers

Hello I am preparing map portal for one city. It will website with few maps aplications. What is better to use?
classic HTML, CSS, Javascript, OpenLayers, Geoserver, PostGIS or **React**, OpenLayers, Geoserver, PostGIS.

Thank you.

I tried write in html and css, but I think that react can be better through components.

Answer (score 0):

Best is what you already know and you feel comfortable with. Designing a complex system with new technology that you do not master is a challenging and error-prone process.

If you have to learn something new, go with the most modern approach as this will be the best long-term investment - in this case it would be React.

Bear in mind that using React won't completely replace CSS or HTML. The only advantage will be a structured application where complexity will be easier to handle.

Just be aware that working with Openlayers from React is not easy as it is not designed around its component life-cycle principles. But you can always try my React components: https://github.com/mmomtchev/rlayers which are targeted at the novice React user.